# How combine time-interval and domtree-changed-event-listener-function?

Tags: jquery, dom, timer, event-listener

Following problem. I want to calculate the time remaining for an upload. There is already a progress bar where 100% uploaded would mean that the value of the progress bar would be 1. The passed time is known too. The progress bar is updated every few milliseconds. What I want to do is to update the time remaining every minute.

I tried to use following functions:

```
$('#bars progress').bind('DOMSubtreeModified',function(e){ 
    if($('#bars progress').is(':visible') && $('#bars progress').val()<1){ //progress bar shows up after clicking the upload button
        setInterval(rem_time, 60000); //fire function to show remaining time in console every minute
    }
});

function rem_time(){
    var prog_value = $('#bars progress').val(); 
    var now = $.now();
    var passed=now-time; //time is the start time of the upload
    console.log('passed in milliseconds'+passed);
    var remaining=Math.ceil((((1.0/prog_value)*passed)/60000)); // time remaining in minutes
    console.log('remaining: '+remaining);                   
}
```

But the rem_time function is fired way too often and not just every minute so I guess I didn't combine the timeout function and the domtree change function correctly. How to do it correctly?

Comment: why are you using `DOMSubtreeModified` ? and your saying both `timeout` and `interval` which one of the two are you trying to use?

Comment: Well, I want to fire the function that shows the time remaining every minute after the first time the progress bar changes the value